# Binding data context changes when using vustom ContentView control

Tags: xaml, binding, maui, datacontext, compiled-bindings

I have the following code:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Creature.FriendlyEnvironment}"
          x:DataType="vm:PlantDetailsViewModel">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" x:DataType="m:Creature" />
                <!--<v:ListviewItemView Creature="{Binding .}" x:DataType="m:Creature" />-->
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When I execute this code, the Label has the correct data context, and I can use the Create Name property.
But if I want to use the commented out code, I got the following error:

> 'GardenerMaster.Views.ListviewItemView' cannot be converted to type 'GardenerMaster.Models.Creature'

Could you please help me, how can I pass the current item to my ListviewItemView?

ListviewItemView.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class ListviewItemView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CreatureProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(Creature), returnType: typeof(Creature), declaringType: typeof(ListviewItemView), defaultValue: default(Creature));

    public Creature Creature
    {
        get => (Creature)GetValue(CreatureProperty);
        set => SetValue(CreatureProperty, value);
    }

    public ListviewItemView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ListviewItemView.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="GardenerMaster.Views.ListviewItemView"
    x:DataType="v:ListviewItemView">
    <Label Text="{Binding Creature.Name}" />
</ContentView>
```

I tried various way to pass the current item, but none of them worked.

```xml
<v:ListviewItemView Creature="{Binding}" x:DataType="m:Creature" />
<v:ListviewItemView Creature="{Binding .}" x:DataType="m:Creature" />
<v:ListviewItemView Creature="{Binding Path=.}" x:DataType="m:Creature" />
```

I also tried to set the `x:DataType="m:Creature"` for the DataTemplate, but it did not work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing that error, because you're mixing up the different data types in the [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings).

You should declare the `x:DataType` on the `DataTemplate`:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="m:Creature">
    <ViewCell>
        <v:ListviewItemView />
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

and make sure to use the **same** declaration on the `ListviewItemView`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:GardenerMaster.Models"
    x:Class="GardenerMaster.Views.ListviewItemView"
    x:DataType="m:Creature">
    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
</ContentView>
```

You also don't need the bindable property in the code-behind, that's redundant *(to say the least)*:

```cs
public partial class ListviewItemView : ContentView
{
    public ListviewItemView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The control inherits its `BindingContext` from the `DataTemplate`, so you can directly bind to `Name` instead of `Creature.Name`.